# Spamassassin rule that compares part of the To: header with part of the subject line

Tags: regex, rule, subject, spamassassin

I am trying to write a rule that will trigger when the user part of the 'To:' header is present in the subject line, followed by a number or preceded by a number.

For example

```
To: myname@thisdomain.com
Subject: myname 3679273
```

or

```
To: john.doe@thatdomain.com
Subject: 72835 john.doe
```

There is an existing rule that checks if the entire To address is present in the subject (TO_IN_SUBJ). I am looking for something similar, but I want to test only for the part before the @ in the To address. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As-is spamassassin rules don't have this ability to directly to compare header A to header B.  You need to script something to do it.

Comment: Yeah, I eventually figured that out. Thanks though for replying. I'll give you the points.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is not true.

You can write complex rules like:

```
header      RULE_EXAMPLE_FROM        From =~ /\@example.com/i
header      RULE_EXAMPLE_SUBJECT     Subject =~ /whatever/i
meta        RULE_EXAMPLE             RULE_EXAMPLE_FROM && RULE_EXAMPLE_SUBJECT
score       RULE_EXAMPLE             +2000
describe    RULE_EXAMPLE             Spam caught
```

Comment: The original question was: 

"a rule that will trigger when the user part of the 'To:' header is present in the subject line".

I do not see how your solution solves that problem. 
I can change From to To, as asked, but even then. Where do you search the subject for the username part from the To address? You use literals, but the rule cannot use literals because the "example.com" and "whatever" are not know up front.

Can you please elaborate your solution?